# Unity UI: When sizing an object, it's children don't change scale, but only position

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, scale, unity-ui

I've made a little demonstration image:

[Demonstration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVjvr.png)

If I try to change the scales of an background-image, which is set to fill the screen, the objects inside of the image, the children, only change their position. But they don't change their size, so they don't strech. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the first setting to "listed" instead of false...